# Adding an "I'm working on it"-flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

Often, when I'm about to give an answer to a question, other users post the same thing right before me, rendering my work useless. This is kind of frustrating.

I would love to see a flag that indicates if another user is about to give an answer. When I see that it is a user with high reputation I wouldn't have to start on researching or writing something down.

An example: often questions to a specific topics are answered by the same 2-3 users at a specific time of day. I know these users/their names and if I see that they are the ones answering it, I can be sure that this answer will be of high quality. So that would be a good reason to save time and concentrate on other questions.

Specifically:

- the flag shouldn't be permanent, maybe visible for 5 minutes
- the flag shouldn't be set automatically, users may choose to set it and maybe should only be able to set it once, so you can't "block" a question
- only seeing that a question is flagged doesn't mean that there is no reason to answer it
- other users should be able to see who flagged the question
- additionally there could be a short hint where that answer is headed (e.g. *"wrong use of objects"*), so you would know if your answer will be a duplicate or not

Comment: It's been asked on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244602/alert-that-a-user-is-typing-a-comment-or-answer). I'm quite convinced that it won't solve the issue you want to solve and the implementation of a system that would not be prone to abuse would get complicated quick.

Comment: And what if you set that signal to let everyone else know you are working on it and then you get frustrated and give up, when does that "flag" go away?  And why would someone not answer anyway?  How will they know their answer is identical to yours?  And why should your answer get priority over another?

Comment: You've just moved the race condition, not eliminated it.

Comment: I don't know if the suggestion is the best, but a lot of people writes a line in the answer, and then they make 4, 5 or even 10 editions to complete the answer. I think that we need a system to avoid crazy things like this. Maybe not a flag, but something different.

Comment: Edit: Added more details to question.

Comment: "only seeing that a question is flagged, doesn't mean, that there is no reason to answer it" So let's have a flag that we're going to ignore anyway!

Comment: @Marcos `I think that we need a system to avoid crazy things like this.` why?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you're saying that this is too rare to be dealt with I can aussre you that it is (at least for me) very common.

Comment: Hehe, the only thing such a flag would ever accomplish is to get other users to submit their answer quicker :)   A standard "fastest gun in the west" technique is to post a brief answer first and then edit it to expand it.  If you submit the edit within the 5 minute grace period then it isn't even visible that you edited it.  You do run the risk of getting DVs if the brief answer isn't good enough but that doesn't happen very often on the kind of questions that attract FGITW answers.

Comment: @Tom No, I'm asking why you guys think it is a problem.

Comment: Provide a line with very bad explanation of the answer itself, to let editing through the next minutes, cause problems of writing and to contrast the information. This cause common problems like answers with insuficient explanation, or answers with a solution but poor quality in the letter.

Comment: @Marcos so downvote the poor quality answers, and upvote the good quality answers from those who put in more effort. I still don't understand how repeated editing is a problem here.

Comment: My incentive to provide answers on SO is not getting the highest score or boosting my reputation. It’s about helping people so they are able to fix their problems. If I’m investing 20 minutes on an answer (whatever score it might get me) and then see another one posted 5 minutes before mine with more or less the same content, it frustrates me and this lowers my motivation to participate more.

Comment: `My incentive to provide answers on SO is not getting the highest score or boosting my reputation.` then it won't matter to you who else is answering. No? It hasn't mattered to me in six years - unless someone had already provided a good answer to the question.

Comment: It's about investing time, not about rivalry.

Comment: Then wait a while to see whether anyone else might provide the same answer you would have.

Comment: Users hope to get their answers quickly and sometimes time is of the essence. Also other users might wait as well (probably already do now) to give an answer, wasting even more time for everyone.

Comment: Working on an answer...

Comment: *Users hope to get their answers quickly and sometimes time is of the essence.* It's nice if you want to help people as fast as possible but the site makes no promises of speedy answers. No one posting a question should have the *expectation* that it will be answered quickly. In fact, if you're having this problem a lot you may want to start looking at older unanswered questions.

Answer (score 17):

This would paralyze activity on the site.

The system as it stands now  encourages the maximum in participation.

If 5 people provide the same answer, there are ways for you to make yours shine - more detail, good reference links, nice formatting, etc.

The incentive for all this would go away if we could see that Jon Skeet (or whoever) is answering a question, because we'd often feel discouraged from providing an alternative answer. Many of us would just assume that the person writing an answer is writing a better one, and walk away. The site would wither and die, or at least see a massive drop in participation and answer quality.

If you don't like 5 people providing answers, find more difficult/obscure questions and tags.

Comment: _"If 5 people provide the same answer"_ - then you're answering a shitty question, a duplicate or both.

Answer (score 6):

I'm against this feature request.

Yes, it is frustrating but your proposal does not in fact fix the problem you are trying to fix.

I guarantee you that people are going to set the flag even when an answer won't materialize. Sometimes you may honestly think you are going to answer but find that you misunderstood the question (happened to me), or that you're not going to be able to answer (yep, happened to me too) and abandon. **After users notice people setting the flag but not answering a few times, they are going to start disregarding the flag and we're back to square one.**

**I disagree with the idea that you should not answer because someone who is knowledgeable is writing an answer.** There are a couple tags on SO in which I'm the top answerer. I know the technologies inside and out. There have been times where I posted an answer that was correct but required more know-how on the part of readers. And someone posted an answer that they wrote at the same time I was writing mine that fixed the problem in a way that was more readily comprehensible to a wider audience. Their answer was useful to more people than mine. It would have been a shame if they did not post it.

Comment: Good point on correct answer not answering OP's question. Especially if it ends up XY-problem question would need to be edited and Y part should be answered too.